# Adding dynamic objects to ColumnLayout in a ScrollView

Tags: qt, qml

I have a ScrollView, that handles a RawLayout with 4 ColumnLayouts in it.
There are several dynamically created Rectangles via `Qt.createComponent(...)`, which are added into Columns.

I'm stuck, trying to dynamically add objects into Column, so ScrollView should handle Column's growing content, but it seems doesn't work because of when `Qt.createComponent(...).createObject(parentID)`, `parentID` — is my Column's id, not a ScrollView's (which is required, according to documentation).

```qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Rectangle {
    id: root
    //anchors.fill: parent
    height: 1600
    width: 1400
    color: "black"

    function createTestModule()
    {
        var component = Qt.createComponent("TestModule.qml"); //TestModule.qml is just a red rectangle
        if (component.status === Component.Ready)
            var obj = component.createObject(testLyt);
        else
            console.log(component.errorString())
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: buttonContainer
        width: 60
        height: 15
        color: "darkgrey"
        z: 1

        Button {
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

            Text {
                text: qsTr("TestModule+")
                color: "black"
                font.pointSize: 8
                width: parent.width
            }

            onClicked: {
                createTestModule();
            }
        }
    }

    ScrollView
    {
        id: scroll
        width: 400
        height: 400
        ScrollBar.horizontal.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        ScrollBar.vertical.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn

        Rectangle {
            id: container
            color: "dimgray"
            //anchors.top: buttonContainer.bottom
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            smooth: true

            Row {
                id: rowLyt
                spacing: 0

                Column
                {
                    id: testLyt
                    spacing: 10
                }
                Column
                {
                    id: testLyt1
                    spacing: 10
                }
                Column
                {
                    id: testLyt2
                    spacing: 10
                }
                Column
                {
                    id: cubicLyt3
                    spacing: 10
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that in the ScrollView it is necessary to wrap the Layout directly, and not the container (Rectangle):

```javascript
Rectangle {
  ScrollView {
    Row {
     Column {} 
     Column {} 
     Column {} 
    }  
  }
}
```